@nestjs/schedule throws Error on macOS: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SchedulerMetadataAccessor
I use NestJS in the latest version (10.3.10) on macOS 14.5. For time-based scheduling, I installed @nestjs/schedule also in the latest version (4.1.0). After that, I implemented the code for the module in the app module like this: ScheduleModule.forRoot(). The Tasks service is also correctly implemented in my project.
My problem is when I try to start my server, it throws this error:
03.07.2024 14:26:09 error:    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SchedulerMetadataAccessor (?). Please make sure that the argument Reflector at index [0] is available in the ScheduleModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Reflector is a provider, is it part of the current ScheduleModule?
- If Reflector is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ScheduleModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Reflector */ ]
  })

After one hour trying to solve these problem I started the Server on my Windows-VM and it works directly.
Does anybody have a solution for this Problem on my macOS system?
I didn't found anything on google for this problem so i home anybody can help. thanks

I had this same issue while using a pnpm monorepo on macOS. I was able to resolve it by moving the @nestjs/core dependency from the package.json of my backend workspace to package.json at the root of the monorepo. (Note that it was necessary to uninstall it from the workspace, not to just duplicate it at the root.)
